# Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll' [using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB version 3.0.0-beta7]

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the following packages.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.0-beta7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Analyzers.Compatibility" Version="0.2.12-alpha" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="stream-net" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I am using Visual studio version 15.6.4 with Azure Functions and WebJob Tools version 15.0.4045.0. Get the following exception when I run a basic CosmosDB changefeed processing function.

```
[12-04-2018 16:32:37] The listener for function 'StreamInserter' was unable to start.
[12-04-2018 16:32:37] The listener for function 'StreamInserter' was unable to start. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)). Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).
[12-04-2018 16:32:37] The listener for function 'StreamInserter' was unable to start. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)). Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).
[12-04-2018 16:32:37]
[12-04-2018 16:32:37] Host started (5716ms)
[12-04-2018 16:32:37] Job host started
[12-04-2018 16:32:37] The following 1 functions are in error:
[12-04-2018 16:32:37] StreamInserter: The listener for function 'StreamInserter' was unable to start. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)). Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Here's the code in my azure function

```
    [FunctionName("StreamInserter")]
    public static void Run(
        [CosmosDBTrigger("db-local", "socialData", ConnectionStringSetting="CosmosDBConnectionString", LeaseDatabaseName ="db-local", LeaseCollectionName = "leases", LeasesCollectionThroughput = 400)]
        IReadOnlyList<Document> changedFeedItems, 
        TraceWriter log,
        ExecutionContext context)
{
                    log.Info($"Received {changedFeedItems.Count} Documents from change feed processor");
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your code in azure function?

Comment: added my function. It doesn't do much right now. But I want to at least see the log message before I proceed further.